# How to request quota increase for Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Before there was an option to request an increase for Google Analytics API in developer console. But I can't find it anymore? Is 50,000 request/day a maximum?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [quotas page for the API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics-json.googleapis.com/quotas) and click:

> Apply for higher quota